# No new mail notification in Thunderbird

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, notification, mail

I am using Thunderbird 31 on Ubuntu. I set up my accounts and then I closed Thunderbird.

But I'm not getting any notification.

Is there any add-on I need?

Comment: Did you close the window or minimize it? If you close it there will of course be no notifications.

Comment: so, i have to leave it in the task bar ... to get notification all the day, cant it set in systemtray and notify me for new mail

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thunderbird needs to be open if you want to get notifications. 
But you can use addons to "hide" it in the tray.

There is an addon called `Minimize to Tray` in Thunderbird to achieve that.  
Once you've installed it press <kbd>F9</kbd> to minimize Thunderbird to the system tray.  
You will keep on receiving the notifications when it is minimized.

Comment: I installed a addon something name like system try, it is working when click minimize button of thunderbird... simply

Comment: Glad it works, if you post the link to the addon as a comment here, I will add it to the answer. I can't test addons atm.

Comment: Do you suggest [MinimizeToTray revived](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/)?

Comment: MinimizeToTray revived should do the same thing yes

Answer (score 4):

Use firetray:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/firetray/

You can configure close button to minimize to tray, control notifications etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird needs to be launched to be able to see new message notifications.

It can be minimized, of course, and the email icon at the top of your screen will turn blue in colour when new mail arrives and the icon in the launcher will indicate the number of emails yet to be read.

You can also enable Workspace Switcher in *System Settings* > *Appearance*> *Behaviour* (if not already done so) and launch Thunderbird in another workspace so that it doesn't detract from screens you use for launching other things.